# ¿Como agregar un elemento a un array de una propiedad de una class?

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, class, push

mi consulta es la siguiente en addMascota debo agregar una mascota al la propiedad mascotas. Esta es la estructura que tengo actualmente:

```
        function crearClaseEmprendedor() {
         class Emprendedor {
          constructor(mascotas) { 
          this.mascotas = mascotas;
        }

        addMascota(mascota) {
        // este método debe agregar una mascota (mascota) al arreglo de mascotas del emprendedor.
        // no debe retornar nada.
        }
```

Este fue mi intento, sin embargo se que esta mal:

```
   `Emprendedor.prototype.mascotas.push(mascota);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Te refieres algo como esto:

```javascript
class Emprendedor {
    mascotas = [];

    constructor(mascotas) {
        this.mascotas = mascotas;
    }

    addMascota(mascota) {
        this.mascotas.push(mascota);
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```javascript
const emprendedor = new Emprendedor(['Rocka', 'Stimpy', 'Rocky' ]);

console.log(emprendedor.mascotas);
emprendedor.addMascota('Manchas');
console.log(emprendedor.mascotas);
```